# Passing Item Tax

Tags: paypal

What is the proper way to pass the tax for each item to the paypal checkout? I have tried this but it does not work.

```
<input type="hidden" name='item_name_1' value='Test Item' />
<input type="hidden" name='item_number_1' value='' />
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value='125.00' />
<input type="hidden" name='discount_amount_1' value='0' />
<input type="hidden" name='tax_1' value='11.2500' />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value='1' />
```

Comment: They compute it themselves based on where the purchaser is and so forth. They don't want you to supply it. I just have a line on the cart page saying that applicable taxes if any will be computed and shown by Paypal prior to payment.

Comment: @EJP, that's not true.  You can absolutely specify tax values yourself, and if you do, it would override your profile setting.

Answer (score 0):

Payments Standard doesn't seem to provide item specific tax parameters.  You would be limited to using either tax or tax_rate.

> **tax**   Optional    Transaction-based tax override variable. Set this variable to a flat tax amount to apply to the payment regardless of
>   the buyer's location. This value overrides any tax settings set in
>   your account profile. Valid only for Buy Now and Add to Cart buttons.
>   Default – Profile tax settings, if any, apply.
>
> **tax_rate**  Optional    Transaction-based tax override variable. Set this variable to a percentage that applies to the amount multiplied by
>   the quantity selected during checkout. This value overrides any tax
>   settings set in your account profile. Allowable values are numbers
>   0.001 through 100. Valid only for Buy Now and Add to Cart buttons. Default – Profile tax settings, if any, apply.

That info is pulled from the [PayPal Standard Variable list](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).  On that list, they don't show anything specific to tax_x parameters under the [shopping cart parameters](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HH0D0TA) section, but they do refer to it within the general parameters...

> **tax_cart**  Optional    Cart-wide tax, overriding any individual item tax_x value

Sounds like that what you tried and it isn't working, so you may have to use the transaction wide parameters.  You could post a sample of your HTML form that you're posting to [PayPal MTS](http://www.paypal.com/mts) and see if they can tell you why it's not working as (somewhat) documented.

Alternatively, if you switch to the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) there are indeed specific parameters available for setting itemized tax values.  That would require programming knowledge of some sort, though.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was using tax_cart and that worked fine. However we need to pass the tax at the item level now. How come the tax_x doesn't work? I can see in the IPN message the tax_1, tax_2, etc but they are always 0.00...

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm with you on that.  According to the documentation it should be working that way.  You could try tax1, tax2, instead of tax_1.  I know it's shown as tax_1, but sometimes they go back and forth and I have seen where the docs have it backwards.  Outside of that the only thing I can say is to submit a sample of what you're sending to PayPal to MTS and hopefully they can confirm a bug or let you know what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Thanks. I have sent an email to PayPal as well. I already tried tax1, tax2, etc without the underscore and that doesn't work either...

Comment: Okay so the issue is that PayPal throws out any values that are not only 2 decimals. Hope that helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even notice that.  That's interesting, though. They used to return an invalid amount error when that was the case rather than simply ignore it.